# Submit for two models at once > Registration for Devise + Data for Model (scaffold)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, submit

I´m trying to submit two forms with one f.submit but apparently the <% end %> gets in the way.
This works saving Devise but not the model:

```
<%= form_for(@babysitter) do |f| %> 

Data fields Input for Model created with Scaffold

<% end %>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

Data fields Input for Devise

<%= f.submit "Registrarse" %>
<% end %>
```

When I put them the other way a devise error notice appears saying the email and password of the devise input fields are empty.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

Data fields Input for Devise  

<% end %>

<%= form_for(@babysitter) do |f| %> 

Data fields Input for Model created with Scaffold

<%= f.submit "Registrarse" %>
<% end %>
```

I very new to rails as you can see and I know is a very basic question but I just can´t get around it.
Any help is wellcome

Answer (score 0):

You can not submit two models with one submit in rails. You need to define associations between the models and use one submit which will automatically populate the form data in both the tables.

Set your models up like so:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :question
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :question, :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

Then you can write your form using rails helpers like this:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :question do |question_form| %>
   <%= question_form.text_field :question
  <% end %>
  <%= form.fields_for :answers do |answer_form| %>
   <%= question_form.text_field :answer
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller action that will render the form you need to build the new records in memory like this:

```
class SurveyController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    @survey.build_question
    @survey.answers.build
  end
end
```

Check this railscast it will give you a better idea:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1